# Disable ido mode for write file

Tags: key-bindings, ido, overwrite

I was not the only one who thought `ido` is very inconvenient when trying to write a new file. The emacs wiki has a section dedicated to disabling `ido` for `write-file`:

[Disable ido mode for particular commands, e.g. write-file](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings#toc33)

Their suggestion is to turn off `ido` for write file using:

```
 (define-key (cdr ido-minor-mode-map-entry) [remap write-file] nil)
```

This does not seem to work for me. `ido` still runs when I hit `C-x C-w`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I know I can exit ido with C-f. That is not a satisfactory solution.

Comment: FYI:  The `ido.el` library is disabled by default when starting with `emacs -q` -- i.e., no user configuration.  If you start with no user configuration and then type `M-x eval-expression RET (featurep 'ido) RET` you will see that the return value is `nil` because it is not loaded by default.

Comment: I too am annoyed by this. My solution is just type file name and hit C-j.

Comment: Lawlist, `(featurep 'ido)` returns t. So I assume the user configuration is loaded.

Comment: Xah Lee (honored), My motivation is that I need to save frequent iterations of a file (long_filename_01, long_filename_02, etc. and git style versioning is not an option) so I use C-x C-w C-f M-n to edit just the last character in the filename. That is lot of chording for such a common and important action.

Comment: @Snelephant I posted an answer. Try that, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following should work.

```
(require 'ido)
(ido-mode)
(define-key (cdr ido-minor-mode-map-entry) [remap write-file] nil)
```

the problem was caused by ido not initialized. Need the `(ido-mode)` line there.

Comment: The second line produces `Wrong type argument: keymapp, nil`

Comment: that means for some reason you don't have ido-minor-mode-map-entry defined. (the cdr part  of that variable should be a keymap, but you got nil) What emacs version are you using? also, did you run that require ido line?

Comment: The code is in my init.el exactly as shown in your answer, including the require ido line. No other references to ido in my initialization. Version: Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)

Comment: i modified the answer. need the (ido-mode) line. try that. I tried, worked now. also on emacs 25.1.

Comment: If you use `(setq ido-everywhere t)` you'll need also `(add-to-list 'ido-read-file-name-non-ido 'write-file)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `C-x C-f C-f` to bypass [ido-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ido.html) when it gets in the way.

To "save as", same: `C-x C-w C-w` but this time you stay in ido-mode, only you can edit the prompt.

Comment: I think it's C-f to bypass ido-mode even when in "Write file"